# (fluxus) learning curve

Tags: scheme, osc

I'm trying to have some fun with fluxus, but its manual and online docs all seem to assume that the reader is already an expert network programmer who's never heard of Scheme before. Consequently, you get passages that try to explain the very basics of prefix notation, but assume that you know how to pipe sound-card data into the program, or setup and connect to an OSC process.

Is there any tutorial out there that goes the opposite way? IE, assumes that you already have a handle on the Lisp/Scheme thing, but need some pointers before you can properly set up sound sources or an OSC server?

Barring that, does anyone know how to get (for example) the system microphone to connect to (fluxus), or how to get it to play a sound file from disk?

Comment: Can't answer your question but didn't know about flexus and after playing with it for 10 minutes I'm loving it :-)

Hope someone helps you out - in the meantime thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Agreed, it's sweet, but its documentation is all out of date or assumes a very high level of proficiency in network programming.
For example, you can set it up to work in DrScheme, but the process they describe doesn't work (I assume it once did). 
It is also possible to run it from Emacs, but the actual instructions are "just set up Emacs to send OSC info to the fluxus scratchpad". That assumes that I know what OSC is and that I know how to configure Emacs to send it (and I haven't found a more specific description of how to do it).
Maybe I should try asking multiple, more specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

To get the system microphone to connect to fluxus you need a software to comunicate and take the data in your audio card, like jackpilot http://www.jackosx.com/about.html

Once you have installed in your computer (mac in this case):

1. go to system preferencies/audio... in audio IN, you need to select your microphone
2. strart jackpilot
3. in jackpilot preferences configure audio IN to microphone too
4. put in buffer size 1024, and sample rate 44100
5. save (jackpilot) and click run
6. open fluxus
7. try this little code

   ```
   (clear)

   (start-audio "" 1024 44100)

   (define (something)

     (rotate (vector (gh 0) (gh 5) (gh 15)))

     (draw-cube)

    )   

   (every-frame (something))
   ```

If you need the same info in linux, tell me.

If you need to do the same on windows... windows do not have audio support.

I hope this info works for you.